# Angular difference between ${ value } and {{ value }}

Tags: angular

I've been reading tutorials on Angular and some people seem to be using following syntax within their templates `${ value }` it seems to produce similar value as simply using `{{ value }}` so I started wondering why add the dollar sign? Is this done for some semantics or does it actually have its functionality?

Comment: I think its `${value}`

Comment: @PankajParkar Corrected, thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`${someVar}` is string interpolation from TS and is applied before the template is processed by angular. 
`{{someVar}}` is Angular template binding expression.

Comment: So setting ${someVar} means that value will always remain the same, despite someVar changes?

Comment: Yes, `someVar` will be read when Angular compiles the template and is static afterwards.

Answer (score 4):

To complete what Günter said, the `${someVar}` corresponds to the string interpolation feature of ES6. This can be used within strings defined between the charater ` (back-tick). This also allows to define string on several lines.

Here is a sample

```
let someVar = '10';
let someString = `The value of someVar is ${someVar}`;
```

It's something that can be used outside Angular2 with ES6.

See this link for more details: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/01/ES6-Template-Strings.

Hope it helps you,
Thierry